# Row color based on contents in the ListView of my RSS reader

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am very much an Android newbie and I have built a simple RSS reader application based around the free IBM android RSS tutorial. I would like to change the background color of each row if the category of that row is equal to a particular String.

I wrote the following "for loop" which discovers the category of each item and runs an if statement should that category be equal to "News". At the moment the background colour of the entire listview gets changed as soon as a feed is supplied with a News category.

Does anyone out there feel like helping out a beginner?

```
for(int i = 0; i < feed.getItemCount(); i++)
{
    if (feed.getItem(i).getCategory().equals("News"))
    {
       ListView.setBackgroundColor(0x77ee0044);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you include a link to the tutorial so we can be more specific?

Comment: Hi Matthew, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-androidrss/index.html

Comment: private void UpdateDisplay()
    {
        TextView feedtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedtitle);
        TextView feedpubdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedpubdate);
        ListView itemlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemlist);
        
        ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,feed.getAllItems());

        itemlist.setAdapter(adapter);
        
        itemlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        
        itemlist.setSelection(0);
             
     return;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to do this inside the `getView()` method of your adapter.

Before you return the view in getView(), you can call [setBackgroundColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29) on the view or use one of the other `setBackgroundFoo()` methods.

**Edit** - given your code, when you create your Adapter, try:

```
ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(
  this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,feed.getAllItems(­)) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (getItem(position).getCategory().equals("News")) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000); // red
        }
        return view;
    }
};
```

This overrides [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) to adjust the background of your list item views properly.

Comment: Thanks so much Matthew, I had spent hours going around in circles.

Comment: No problem. I was surprised that this could be done in such little code.